# Breaking framed boxes across pages - or, a better design for a homework problem set?

Tags: page-breaking, boxes

My school's recommended homework document class file uses a `boxedminipage` to typeset problem statements so they appear in a box. However, this has the unfortunate consequence that they can't be broken across pages — so problem statements frequently tend to push themselves onto a new page.

Is there a way around this, such that the box can be broken across pages? Or does anyone have any better suggestions for a way to visually offset the problem statements from the solutions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a short example using the [`mdframed` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) that is capable of breaking a boxed environment across a page:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\newmdtheoremenv[outerlinewidth=2,leftmargin=40,rightmargin=40,%
    backgroundcolor=yellow,outerlinecolor=blue,innertopmargin=0pt,%
    splittopskip=\topskip,skipbelow=\baselineskip,%
    skipabove=\baselineskip,ntheorem,roundcorner=5pt]{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{theorem}[Your important theorem]
\lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

See the [`mdframed` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) for more information on how the `mdframed` environment can be used. In the above example, [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was used to generate dummy text, *Lorem Ipsum* style.