# Shadowbox that breaks page

Tags: boxes, minipage

I am trying to typeset a block of text in `shadowbox`. The text is quite long, therefore I would like it to span across two pages where necessary. TeX will not perform a pagebreak, though.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{centering}
\shadowbox{%
\begin{minipage}[c]{5in}
\sf
Data warehousing seems to be a big trend these days, and is very interesting to me. 
I'm trying to acquaint myself with its concepts, and am having a problem "seeing 
the forest through the trees" because all of the data warehouse models descriptions 
I can find online are theoretical, but don't gives examples with actual technologies 
being used. I'm a contextual learner, so abstracted, theoretical explanations don't 
really help me out all that much. \linebreak 
...
\end{minipage}}
\end{centering}
\vspace{10pt}
```

I reckon `minipage` is the problem. I have experimented with `mdframed, lstset` and also `lstinputlisting` with no desired results. Any proposed solution that will look like this output will be welcome:

[image: http://postimage.org/image/8645fzlyx/]

Comment: Have a look at the package mdframed.

Comment: Which problems did you have with mdframed?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Breaking framed boxes across pages - or, a better design for a homework problem set?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35504/5764) after adding the [`xcolor` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) and the option `shadow=true`. Does this help?

Comment: See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43207/drop-shadow-framed-environment-using-mdframed-tikz

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `mdframed` package does what you need (after loading the `shadows` library for TikZ):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newmdenv[shadow=true,shadowcolor=black,font=\sffamily,rightmargin=8pt]{shadedbox}

\begin{document}


\begin{shadedbox}
Data warehousing seems to be a big trend these days, and is very interesting to me. 
I'm trying to acquaint myself with its concepts, and am having a problem "seeing 
the forest through the trees" because all of the data warehouse models descriptions 
I can find online are theoretical, but don't gives examples with actual technologies 
being used. I'm a contextual learner, so abstracted, theoretical explanations don't 
really help me out all that much.
\end{shadedbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update

Another option, using this time `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newtcolorbox{shadedbox}{
  drop shadow southeast,
  breakable,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  colback=white,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{shadedbox}
Data warehousing seems to be a big trend these days, and is very interesting to me. 
I'm trying to acquaint myself with its concepts, and am having a problem "seeing 
the forest through the trees" because all of the data warehouse models descriptions 
I can find online are theoretical, but don't gives examples with actual technologies 
being used. I'm a contextual learner, so abstracted, theoretical explanations don't 
really help me out all that much.
\end{shadedbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice suggestion, is this possible to fix the gradient for the shadows? Please advise.